# Insert an element to a variable size matrix at specific locations in R Studio

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix called sectorCoor which contains a list of 18 lat long coordinates. These 18 coordinates are dependent upon another variable which could change the size of the matrix from a minimum of 6 to a maximum of 36. The matrices will always be a multiple of 6. So depending upon the size of the sectorCoor matrix I would like to divide the existing matrix into elements of size 6 and from there I would like to add the variable siteCoor to the very start of the sectorCoor matrix and again after the first 6 elements, add siteCoor and take the next 6 and so on and so on until all multiples of 6 have been completed.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
 siteCoor, 
 first 6 lon lat coordinates
 siteCoor
 siteCoor
 Next 6 lon lat coordinates
 siteCoor
 siteCoor
 Next 6 lon lat coordinates
 siteCoor

> siteCoor
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 152.7075 -27.7027

> sectorCoor
           lon       lat
 [1,] 152.7075 -27.70270
 [2,] 152.6983 -27.68203
 [3,] 152.7028 -27.68085
 [4,] 152.7075 -27.68046
 [5,] 152.7122 -27.68085
 [6,] 152.7167 -27.68203
 [7,] 152.7209 -27.68394
 [8,] 152.7322 -27.70592
 [9,] 152.7311 -27.71000
[10,] 152.7291 -27.71382
[11,] 152.7264 -27.71724
[12,] 152.7230 -27.72015
[13,] 152.7190 -27.72243
[14,] 152.6920 -27.72015
[15,] 152.6886 -27.71724
[16,] 152.6858 -27.71382
[17,] 152.6839 -27.71000
[18,] 152.6828 -27.70592
[19,] 152.6825 -27.70173
```

Comment: Why does ´sectorCoor` has 19 rows although you claim it should have 18? Please, give an example of the expected output. I'm not sure I did understand your request. Thank you.

Comment: Do I get you right that you don't mean the arithmetic operation of adding numbers when you use the term _add_? Do you man _insert_, perhaps?

Comment: Hi Uwe Block, sectorCoor has 19 rows instead of 18 since I performed an rbind with siteCoor 'sectorCoor <- rbind(siteCoor,polygonCoor)'. polygonCoor has the same 18 coordinates above less the first coordinate pair as this is the site coordinate, apologies for the confusion. You are correct regarding the second point, I did mean insert and not add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would preallocate a matrix of the correct size, and separately populate the `siteCoor` and `sectorCoor` rows. We can use the initial data vector passed to `matrix()` to populate the `siteCoor` rows, and then use an index-assignment to populate the `sectorCoor` rows.

```
res <- matrix(siteCoor,nrow(sectorCoor)+nrow(sectorCoor)%/%6L*2L,2L,byrow=T);
res[c(F,rep(T,6L),F),] <- sectorCoor;
res;
##       [,1] [,2]
##  [1,]   -1   -2
##  [2,]    1   19
##  [3,]    2   20
##  [4,]    3   21
##  [5,]    4   22
##  [6,]    5   23
##  [7,]    6   24
##  [8,]   -1   -2
##  [9,]   -1   -2
## [10,]    7   25
## [11,]    8   26
## [12,]    9   27
## [13,]   10   28
## [14,]   11   29
## [15,]   12   30
## [16,]   -1   -2
## [17,]   -1   -2
## [18,]   13   31
## [19,]   14   32
## [20,]   15   33
## [21,]   16   34
## [22,]   17   35
## [23,]   18   36
## [24,]   -1   -2
```

In the above I use a short logical vector to subscript the `sectorCoor` rows of `res`. R recycles the vector across the entire row size of `res`, achieving the required periodicity of the storage pattern.

**Data**

```
N <- 3L;
sectorCoor <- matrix(seq_len(N*6L*2L),ncol=2L);
siteCoor <- matrix(c(-1,-2),ncol=2L);
```